# How to add Gradle testCompile dependency to WebArchive using ShrinkWrap for Arquillian?

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I have the following dependency on my `gradle.build` file, which I don't want to be placed on my final `war` file, but I need it in order to run `Arquillian` tests on test phase:

```
/* Snippet from build.gradle. */
testCompile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.48.2'
```

If I were using Maven, I could write something like:

```
File[] files = Maven.resolver().resolve("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.48.2").withTransitivity().asFile();
```

But, since I'm using Gradle resolver, I believe I can't do that:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public abstract class ArquillianTestCase extends SeleniumTestCase {

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {

        /* Create the war file according to build.gradle. */
        WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(EmbeddedGradleImporter.class)
                .forThisProjectDirectory().importBuildOutput()
                .as(WebArchive.class);

        /* Abstract test classes which depends on Selenium */
        war.addClasses(ArquillianTestCase.class, SeleniumTestCase.class);
        return war;
    }
}
```

Is there a way of doing this on Gradle? If I don't add the said dependency, my tests fail by `NoClassDefFoundError` on Selenium classes. However, if I change Selenium dependency to `compile` instead of `testCompile`, it works, but my war file size jumps from 3 to 20 megabytes, filled with test classes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally although you are using Gradle, you still can use those maven parts, since probably all your dependencies are in maven repositories. However sometimes you might need to explicitly define additionally maven repositories, since you don't have pom which sets them and ShrinkWrap can't set them automatically.

You can combine these two provided by you calls into sth similiar to this:

```
File[] files = Maven.resolver().resolve("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.48.2").withTransitivity().asFile();

WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(EmbeddedGradleImporter.class)
                .forThisProjectDirectory().importBuildOutput()
                .as(WebArchive.class).addAsLibraries(files);
```

Of course you have to add dependency for ShrinkWrap Resolver maven related modules.

```
testCompile 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven:2.2.0'
testCompile 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven:2.2.0'
```

Btw, won't Arquillian Graphene solve your issue related to using both Selenium and Arquillian?

Comment: You're right! I can use Maven parts even if my project isn't Maven or has a `pom.xml` file, because the `Maven.resolver().resolve(String)` call do all the work, no matter what kind of project it is running on. Thanks @mmatloka.
I've never considered Graphene since the given approach seems to work, but, could you present some benefits of using Graphene?